# javascript (or Django/Python): detect if touch screen

Tags: javascript, django

How can I detect whether a user is using a touch screen? This can be in Python/Django or in javascript.

Comment: Why do you need to care? What is wrong with  [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)?

Comment: If it's a touchscreen then I want my input to have a calendar icon that makes the calendar pop up. If it's not a touchscreen then I don't need this icon - the calendar pops up when the input has focus.

Comment: I'd put the icon in anyway — if nothing else it is a visual indication that there is a calendar widget available. The only negative to having it is using slightly more screen estate.

Comment: I'll run it by some users and see what they like. And read about  Progressive Enhancement and Unobtrusive JavaScript :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function is_touch_device() {
  return !!('ontouchstart' in window)
      || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window);
};
```